# How do I leave H-047c?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

H-047c is an asteroid that used to be one of the golden worlds, it has very low gravity and extremely high surface radiation which prevents you from leaving the Nomad.

Not being able to leave the Nomad prevents you from interacting with anything, including the Tempest to leave at the end of the mission.

How do I leave H-047c?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As it turns out, there is a specific key binding to return to the Tempest from the Nomad which can be configured in settings.

In the default instance on PC this is <kbd>T</kbd> although you're not prompted to press this at any point during or after the mission and during my entire play through I don't remember this being prompted at any time.

On PS4 the default binding is triangle, and on XBox the binding is the Y button.

[image: extraction to the Tempest from within the Nomad]

Comment: What's the console variety of the T binding?